# Write x as function of y with sin

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Is it possible to write the equation $x+y\sin{x}=1$ in terms of $x=f(y$)? I can easily solve for $y$, but am not sure how to approach $x$.

Comment: You can't. The $f$ you want, if it exists, would be the inverse function of $g(x)=\frac{1-x}{\sin x}$. A quick check with [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+%281-x%29%2Fsin%28x%29) reveals that no such function exists, at least not in terms of elementary functions. In this, I assume you're considering $x,y$ as reals with $x$ being non-zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y = \frac{1-x}{\sin x}$ is not a bijection, so the inverse does not exist.